# Meteor: using jQuery to retrieve selected value after clicking submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I retrieve the selected value from the dropdown list created within my form using the following bootstrap classes?

I am using Meteor 0.9.2 and mizzao:bootstrap-3

My HTML:

```
<template name="createpost">
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="createpost">
        <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="field">Field</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option value="one">One</option>
                    <option value="two">Two</option>
                    <option value="three">Three</option>
                    <option value="four">Four</option>
                    <option value="five">Five</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    <input  type="submit" value="post">
</form></template>
```

CLIENT.JS:

```
Template.createpost.events({
'submit form#createpost': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var insertpost = {
        field: //CODE TO RETRIEVE THE VALUE OF THE SELECTED ITEM //
    }
    Meteor.call('insertPostData', insertpost);
} });
```

SEVER.JS:

```
Meteor.methods({
'insertPostData': function(insertpost){
    return insertpost._id = AllPosts.insert(insertpost);
```

}
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I have to give the select an id and then reference this id in the javascript. i used "someId' for this example. This works perfect. Thanks for your initial help though.

```
<template name="createpost">
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="createpost">
    <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="field">Field</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="form-control" id="someId>
                <option value="one">One</option>
                <option value="two">Two</option>
                <option value="three">Three</option>
                <option value="four">Four</option>
                <option value="five">Five</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
<input  type="submit" value="post">
```

client.js:

```
Template.createpost.events({
'submit form#createpost': function(e, tmpl) {
e.preventDefault();
var insertpost = {
    field: $( "#someId" ).val();
}
Meteor.call('insertPostData', insertpost);
} });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Template.createpost.events({
'submit form#createpost': function(e, tmpl) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var selectedOption = tmpl.find('.form-control :selected');

    var insertpost = {
        field: (selectedOption && selectedOption.text)
    }

 }
});
```

Comment: I'm getting an error:
Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function.


According to the console, it is within the code: selectedOption && selectedOption.text(),

I have a comma avert instead of semi colon as I have other fields as well.

This error occurs after I click submit

Comment: My mistake. `selectOption.text` is string not function. Code improved. [Check this](http://meteorpad.com/pad/PYmEZ8cuZLdiSx36c)

Comment: This code also works by getting the string value of the dropdown. So this answer is correct. For my needs, I am working with the value of the option.